# changing and changing back image with jquery

Tags: jquery, image

I found a way to change an image when clicking on it... but im searching to make a loop, means to click again and get back the old image and then click again to get the new image (only 2 images needed).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ChangeImage").click(function(){
$('#ChangeImage').attr('src','image2.jpg');
});
});
</script>
<img src="image1.jpg" name="my_pic" id="ChangeImage">
```

I cant find a way to make it vice versa...thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a function to `attr`, which will pass in the current `src`. Check that before changing:

```
$("#ChangeImage").click(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', function (index, currentSource) {
        return currentSource == 'image2.jpg' ? 'image1.jpg' : 'image2.jpg';
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3yZNT/

---

If you're using a more modern version of jQuery (1.6+), you should use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: Could you explain the `i` and `v` inside the function for me?

Comment: I thought you should only use `prop` if it's a `property`.  However, `src` is really an `attribute` and therefore should use `attr()`.

Comment: Quote:  [_"As of jQuery 1.6, the `.prop()` method provides a way to explicitly retrieve `property` values, while `.attr()` retrieves `attributes`."_](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: @Sparky - Just because the `src` is originally set via an attribute does not mean that it's not a property. [When the DOM is constructed, it'll add that property to the HTML element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr#answer-7572855).

Comment: So by that explanation and logic, I'm having a hard time figuring out when it would be more appropriate to use `attr()` over `prop()`.

Comment: @Sparky - `attr` will get you the value of the attribute, while `prop` will get you the value of the property. Here's a fiddle demonstrating that: http://jsfiddle.net/4tQVS/

Comment: @PaulG.Nahed - What do you mean by "its not working"? Does the fiddle work the way you want it to?

Comment: <html>
<head>
<style>
h1 {
 font-size: 34px;
 padding: 20px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

img {
 display: block;
 margin: 10px auto;
 cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Click the image to toggle it:</h1>
<img id="ChangeImage" src="images/available_seat_img.gif" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js">

var image1 = 'images/available_seat_img.gif';
var image2 = 'images/selected_seat_img.gif';

$("#ChangeImage").click(function () {
    $(this).prop('src', function (index, currentSource) {
        return currentSource == image2 ? image1 : image2;
    });
});
</script>
</body>

Comment: this is the file i created using your code...and yes the fiddle is working fine but my file is not working i dont know why..

Comment: @PaulG.Nahed - That's not how you load scripts. You cannot load anexternal file in the same script that you're putting code into. Use two separate `script` tags: `<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>var image1 = 'images/available_seat_img.gif'; var image2 = 'images/selected_seat_img.gif'; $("#ChangeImage").click(function () { $(this).prop('src', function (index, currentSource) { return currentSource == image2 ? image1 : image2; }); }); </script>`

Comment: @JosephSilber
</head>
<body>
<h1>Click the image to toggle it:</h1>
<img id="ChangeImage" src="images/available_seat_img.gif" />

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
<script>
var image1 = 'images/available_seat_img.gif'; 
var image2 = 'images/selected_seat_img.gif'; 
$("#ChangeImage").click(function () {
 $(this).prop('src', function (index, currentSource)
 { return currentSource == image2 ? image1 : image2; }); }); </script>
</body>
</html>

lol i cant find anything wrong :/..its 1 AM here...when I use those cat photos it works but with my images its not

Comment: yea..i tried to put one cat image and 1 own image it is working and i can change images...but when i put 2 images located in htdocs it only change once from old to new image only..i cnt get back to the old one...very strange

Comment: Quote: _"`attr` will get you the value of the attribute, while `prop` will get you the value of the property."_  Well yeah, I already understand that, hence my very first comment.  But if all `attributes` are also stored as `properties` in the DOM, why would we ever need jQuery `.attr()`, and why is it better to use `.prop()` for `src` when `src` is an `attribute`?

Comment: @Sparky - I linked to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tQVS/) before. When changing the property, the attribute usually won't change with it. If you want access to the original value in the attribute, you can only get to it through `.attr()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it

```
$("#ChangeImage").click(function() {
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
});​

<div id="ChangeImage"><img src="image1.png"/>
<img src="image2.png" style="display:none"/>
</div>
```